# Changing a class variable for multiple instances using a single function

Tags: python-2.7

I want to change the same variable of multiple instances to the same thing using a function. I want to use it for something like this:

```
Class Player:
   arbitrary value = 90
```

I create multiple players and put them in a list:

```
playerlist = [player1,player2,player3]

def changevars(variable,newvariable):
   for x in playerlist:
       x.variable = newvariable
```

But then ofcourse I run into the 'variable not declared issue'.
So what is the proper way to do something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a string with `setattr`:

```
def changevars(players, varname, value):
    for player in players:
        setattr(player, varname, value)
```

You can then use it something like this:

```
changevars(player_list, "arbitrary_value", 5)
```

I made the list of players be an argument instead of a global variable.  This way, you could change the variable either on all players or on only certain ones.  Besides that, global variables are generally considered to be bad practice.